# Get all supported KexAlgorithms of an sftp server

Tags: node.js, bash, sftp

I try to connect with an sftp server using the nodejs package https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2.

In the section "serverHostKey" they list all available host key formats.

I try to connect with a new server, but no matter which format I choose, I cant establish a connection because the format/algorithm is not supported.

Is there a way - a command for the command line - , to see which formats/algorithms a certain server supports?

I already tried WINSCP (shows me only the format WINSCP uses), Putty (same as WINSCP)-

Answer (score -1):

https://superuser.com/questions/868998/how-can-i-find-a-list-of-macs-ciphers-and-kexalgorithms-that-my-openssh-client

The second answer of this question, is the answer of my problem.

```
ssh USER@HOST -p PORT
```